# SSIS package execution in SSIS catalog

Tags: c#, ssis

I want to know if we can restrict the number of instances running at same time of same `ssis package` in `SSIS Catalog` bu using `c#` code. My requirement is, I want to run only 4 instances of `testPackage.dtsx` at the same time ASYNCHRONOUSLY. I tried threading in C# but due to async execution of `SSIS package`, there remains no limit on executions at same time which causes  system hang. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can change an execution parameter to have the package run synchronously:

```
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] 
@execution_id -- your execution ID
@object_type=50, -- 50 is "execution parameter"
@parameter_name=N'SYNCHRONIZED', 
@parameter_value= 1; -- synchronized execution
```

information on these parameters here:
http://www.ssistalk.com/2012/07/24/quick-tip-run-ssis-2012-packages-synchronously-and-other-execution-options/

Then just manage your asnyc calls via C# threading or Task.Run.